# MySQL string manipulation

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I've got a database with a bunch of ip addresses listed in a column. I want to count each time an ip address occurs. But I want to remove all the digits after the last period in the ip address and group by the result. So for an ip address such as `192.178.168.2`, I would want to group by `192.178.168`. Similarly, `192.178.168.234` would be grouped by `192.178.168`.

How do I do this type of string manipulation?

```
select count(*)
from tbl t
group by t.ip_address
order by count(*) desc
limit 10
;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really easy in MySQL because of the function `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(t.ip_address, '.', 3) as TypeC, count(*)
from tbl t
group by substring_index(t.ip_address, '.', 3)
order by count(*) desc
limit 10;
```

This doesn't include the final period.  If you really need that, concatenate it back in.